# Fill Variable with Name information from previous command

Tags: powershell

Having an bit of an issue with my Powershell script. I'm currently running this below -

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | FT Name,OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate -AutoSize
```

Which lists Computers and operating systems in my Active Directory.

I want to fill this variable `$Computers` with the Computer names discovered in my command above.

Anyone got any idea how I do this?

Comment: the main problem with your code is the use of one of the `Format-*` cmdlets. [*grin*] that BUTCHERS your object, _wraps the remnants in formatting code_, and sends that out. **_those cmdlets are intended for final output to the screen or a plain text file_**. the proper cmdlet to use is `Select-Object` since that will give you proper objects that can be used as such in your subsequent steps.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer! `$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,OperatingSystem,LastLogonDate` 

How would I go by using the IF command to remove dates older than 25/10/2019 from the format table ?

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] to filter out by date, use  `Where-Object` and test for `-lt` the date in question. you may need to convert your date _string_ to a date _object_, but that is easy enuf to do.

Comment: Thanks! Did this instead `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,OperatingSystem,LastLogonDate | Where-Object OperatingSystem -Like "Windows 7*" `

Gives me an idea of what is in my enviroment, digging deeper, could you point me in the direction of finding what processors and RAM I have in my enviroment :)

Comment: you may want to take a look at an inventory util like PDQ. [*grin*] however, i did a little tinkering a while ago and did this as a demo of some of the info one can gather ... >>> `[PowerShell] basic remote parallel SystemInfo demo script - Pastebin.com — https://pastebin.com/cGL5biWH` <<<

Answer (score 1):

```
$computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
```

should do the trick. At least it seems to work with a list of file names as in:

```
$filenames = (ls).Name
```